# remove a specific bot

Tags: php, bots

I tried to remove a specific bot as SemrushBot or googlebot (can be other) but it do not work.
Thank you

```
    if(!preg_match('/SemrushBot/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || !preg_match('/googlebot/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
    {
      my code to execute
    }
```

Comment: using `!` is **not**, so your code is saying: *if not SemrushBot or not googlebot, do code*, does that sound right to you?

Comment: yes but I saw always SemrushBot, this code do not block SemrushBot

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. You're not even asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lawrence Cherone gave you already hint but you discarded it.
You condition in an IF statement is always true due to incorrect definition of sets.

This is typical mistake to which are not immune even experienced developers.
It is always hard to interpret complex condition (reconstruct visually picture in mind) when you work with intersections / exclusions of sets which are getting inversed and so on.

What you are trying to achieve is to check whether value DOES NOT belong to specific set of values.

To do it you need to define the set of expected values and then check whether the value belongs to such specific set then you need to invert result of such check to get wanted result.

So you essentially need to check first whether visitor is one the boots

```
$isBot = preg_match('/SemrushBot/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || preg_match('/googlebot/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

and then invert it

```
$humanVisitor =  ! $isBot;
if ( $humanVisitor ){
    //do something specific to human visitors
}
```

or do it in non-user-friendly single liner

```
if(! ( preg_match('/SemrushBot/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || preg_match('/googlebot/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) )){
    //do something specific to human visitors
}
```

**My advice is to split such condition into several lines if possible then anyone who do code review later will have no difficulties with understanding your code**

Comment: Plus 1 for your advice, on splitting the conditions. I would even go further and split, $isGoogleBot, $isSemrushiBot,... Thus the code is CLEAN and easy to understand, even without knowing much context or having to read comments.